# How do I change Keycloak 20.0.0 admin console URL in CentOS7?

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, centos7

I've been searching a lot about how do I change the default url of the admin console of Keycloak in CentOS7.
My current URL is like this schema: `https://my-domain/admin/master/console`, so I want to change the *admin* part to something like `https://my-domain/new-url/master/console`
Most sites say that you can modify the `standalone.xml` file, but I couldn't find that file in version 20.0.0. It seems that this file is not available anymore since version 14.

I hope that someone can help me to solve this big problem, because even I have read all the official documentation, I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered by an official collaborator of Keycloak in the official repo -> https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/22343#discussioncomment-6698977

Original message:

> Unfortunately, selectively changing context root just for admin console is not supported OOTB. However, you should be able to configure a reverse proxy to do that for you. You can then configure the [hostname settings](https://www.keycloak.org/server/hostname#_administration_console) so Keycloak expects your new URL. Note that this settings doesn't actually affect the context root (or ports) that Keycloak uses, it just modifies the redirect URLs, links in the UI etc.